# Symfony4 authenticate against ldap server and fetch user information from database

Tags: ldap, symfony4

I use symfony/ldap to authenticate my users in a Symfony4 project against an active directory (on domain controller). Everything works but now I want to fetch the user information from a local database (according to username or email).
In the official documentation (https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/ldap.html), it's written:

> ... the following scenarios will work: ... Checking a user's password against an LDAP server while fetching user information from another source (database using FOSUserBundle, for example).

But how to do this? How to combine the ldap service for authentication and the user provider (User Entity) for user information?

Best regards,
Jonathan

Comment: This means that you have to redefine https://api.symfony.com/4.1/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/LdapUserProvider.html class and set it as provider in `security` config: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/ldap.html#fetching-users-using-the-ldap-user-provider